# What can templates be used for other than collections

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning c++ and trying to understand templates.

From what I can gather templates are used for defining collections of objects in the case where we don't care what it is as long as all of them are of the same type.

The flip side is that if we need to do an operation on objects provided, polymorphism is a better choice as we have a type which guarantees an implementation of methods.

Is that all there is to it? Or can templates be used for other things? Like anything other than collections.

Comment: [Templates can be used for meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming), and are Turing-complete (they can, in theory, compute anything, though in practice there are practical limits enforced by compilers). In short, templates can be used for *a lot* of things, not just containers/collections.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the standard library.

Comment: Smart pointers?

Comment: With that you can make generic functions, some bit of reflection, duck typing and much much more.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but it isn't exactly a bad question. Just because a question is a beginner question, and not very specific does not necessarily make it bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example paraphrased from Stroustrup himself:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename Iter>
void osprintf(::std::ostream &os, Iter begin, const Iter &end)
{
    bool saw_brace = false;

    while (begin != end) {
        const char c = *begin;

        if (c == '{') {
            saw_brace = true;
        } else if (saw_brace && c == '}') {
            throw ::std::runtime_error("More format specifiers than arguments in osprintf");
        } else if (saw_brace) {
            os << '{' << c;
            saw_brace = false;
        } else {
            os << c;
        }
        ++begin;
    }
    if (saw_brace) {
        os << '{';
    }
}

template<typename Iter, typename T, typename... Args>
void osprintf(::std::ostream &os, Iter begin, const Iter &end, T &&value, Args && ...args)
{
    bool saw_brace = false;

    while (begin != end) {
        const char c = *begin;

        if (c == '{') {
            saw_brace = true;
        } else if (saw_brace && c == '}') {
            os << value;
            osprintf(os, ++begin, end, ::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            return;
        } else if (saw_brace) {
            os << '{' << c;
            saw_brace = false;
        } else {
            os << c;
        }
        ++begin;
    }
    if (saw_brace) {
        os << '{';
    }
    throw ::std::runtime_error("More arguments than format specifiers for osprintf");
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void osprintf(::std::ostream &os, const ::std::string &format, T &&value, Args && ...args)
{
    osprintf(os, format.begin(), format.end(), ::std::forward<T>(value), ::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    osprintf(::std::cout, "This should be a 5: {}, and this should be a 'foobar': '{}'\n", 5, "foobar");
    return 0;
}
```

This is a templatified version of C's `printf` that's type safe and uses '`{}`' for the formatting placeholder. The template program (a program for the compiler to run) looks at the argument list and builds up a printf function that scans the format string for '`{}`' pairs and replaces them with the next value from the argument list. If the number of arguments does not match up with the number of '`{}`' pairs it throws an exception.

Templates in C++ are far, far more powerful than the templates in Java. And this is a purposeful decision by the Java designers. They cut off the power of C++ templates from Java because that power is a significant source of complexity in C++ and they didn't want that complexity in Java. This reason is very similar to why there's no operator overloading in Java and there is in C++.

There are innumerable other examples. Having a program language that your compiler executes to make the program it compiles is extremely powerful, and a feature that was only really available in Common Lisp before C++ templates.

There are very good 'macro' languages (like m4), but those languages are not intertwined with the programs they produce in the same way, and so it's not very easy at all to make good decisions about how the macro should expand based on the details of the language of the program being produced.

C++'s templates are still less powerful than Common Lisps macros. In Common Lisp, macros can be used to create brand new control structures that didn't exist before, and C++'s can generally only be used to create types or functions at compile time.